# reduction of maximum independet set to minimum distance of code

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-theory, np-hardness, coding-theory

Is there a reference for direct reduction of computing maximum independent set of a suitably constructed graph to computing minimum distance of a [linear code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) when the code is specified by its [parity check matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_matrix)?

Comment: maximal indpendent set is NP complete right? so just prove the 1st part ie "reduction of computing minimum distance of code from parity check matrix" [what exactly is that anyway?] is NP complete. then that does not give a "direct" reduction but one can be assured a reduction exists.

Comment: maximal independent set $\neq$ maximum independent set!

Comment: Can you give some reference (like wiki) about "minimum distance of code from parity check matrix"?

Comment: yeah ok Q for poster can he convert to _maximum_ independent set instead given the two problems are closely related

Comment: @SashoNikolov corrected

Comment: @PengZhang http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~pas/code/notes/part12.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the benefit of the others, the minimum code distance problem for codes over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is: given a matrix $H$ ($m$ by $n$, with elements from $\mathbb{F}_2$) and a positive integer $w$, does there exist a vector $x$ such that $Hx = 0$ and the hamming weight (number of 1's) of $x$ is at most $w$.

Since both max ind set and the minimum distance of a linear code are NP complete, there are many-one reductions in either direction. However, it doesn't seem that any of the reductions in the literature that I have seen are directly from max independent set. Actually it seems that the known reductions are from other problems related to coding. Alexander Vardy [proved](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=641542) the NP-hardness of computing the min distance by reducing from the max-likelihood decoding problem: given a matrix $H$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, a vector $s$ and a positive integer $w$, does there exist a vector $x$ such that $Hx = s$ and the weight of $x$ is at most $w$. This problem was shown to be NP-hard by [Berlekamp and others](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5607/) by reduction from [3-dimensional matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) (which is one of the Karp problems and can be reduced to from 3SAT). If you want to reduce max independent set to 3SAT and piece together all these reductions, I guess you can get what you want...

There is a line of work that looks at hardness of approximating the min distance problem. However, reductions there are also from other coding problems. For example, [Dumer and others](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/papers/DMS.pdf) show a hardness of approximation result for the min distance problem by reducing from the nearest codeword problem (given a message find the nearest codeword in hamming distance). A hardness of approximation result for the latter problem was proved by [Arora and others](http://www.di.ens.fr/~stern/data/St49b.pdf), as far as I can tell using two methods: reducing from set cover, or reducing from label cover.